# PubNub show typing indicator

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub, user-presence

We are using PubNub for Chatting, and we are trying to add Typing indicator when a user types. We are trying to send the presence in `state-changed`, using `client.publish` method in swift, with the presence channel, when I publish that, I don't receive any event in `didReceivePresence` callback. I also `subscribedToPresenceChannels`.

Can anybody clarify that, how isTyping indicator feature works with the PubNub? Do we need to use `Presence` (or) `Separate Channel` to maintain?
If we need to do with a `separate channel` then please suggest how can I proceed further

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publish` API designed to work with regular channels and you can't use it to publish some message to presence channel. You get presence messages by [subscribe to a channel `shouldObservePresence` parameter enabled](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/api-reference-sdk-v4#subscribe_arg_1).

You may only listen to presence channels and the PubNub service is the only publisher on the presences channels.

To change state you need to use [`client.setState` API and pass `typing:true` state](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/api-reference-sdk-v4#user-state) there for a particular channel and PubNub will create a `state-change` event on that client's behalf. All clients subscribed with presence enabled on that channel will receive the `state-change` event via the `didReceivePresenceEvent` listener.

Comment: sorry for the delay i'll check and update you with results, thank you

Comment: `didReceivePresenceEvent` firing some times (Most of the time it is not firing) when i'm setting state - `client?.setState` - and i also `subscirbe to channel with presence true`

Comment: and i also checked that i'm setting status in same channel which i have subscribed in another device

Comment: Need logs - repro with [PN logging enabled](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) and upload them somewhere or send to [PubNub support](http://pubnub.com/support)

Comment: @Serhii Mamontov can you check this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945992/pubnub-istyping-status-ionic2

Comment: @CraigConover also you please