# pubnub isTyping status Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, pubnub

I've implemented a chat using Ionic2 with pubnub, the thing is how can I implement the `isTyping` to show it on my `html`? I know I have to create a `state` on my user, but I don't know how to update it.

My [`pubnub service`](https://paste.ofcode.org/bAmiLj58T3WuCrKq9mPaSq) have differents methods, and I thought I could add a `PubNubEventType` that it's called `TYPING` but I don't know how to update it from my component (where I have the chat implemented)

This is my [`component`](https://paste.ofcode.org/35WaRsrMGmJ8hQDRgYiHREa)...

Any ideas?

Comment: You just need to capture key press event to set state true and after a few seconds of no key press events or after publish (send button click), set state false. You set the state using `this. pubNubService.setState(...)` API. [See full docs here](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#user-state). The key press events part is purely JS/Iconic and not PubNub specific so I will leave that to someone else to provide insights.

Comment: And have you followed this blog? https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-03-21-displaying-a-typing-indicator-in-your-angularjs-chat-app/

Comment: Yes I did it but this is angularjs and I use Angular2

Comment: Yes Craig I know it but when I try to implement the setState says that setState is not a function, can you provide a lttle exaple to how to do it please?

Comment: Hey I like the look of pubnub... Did you see in the tutorials there are 2 Angular 2 demos? https://www.pubnub.com/blog/getting-started-with-the-pubnub-angular-2-sdk-part-one/  https://www.pubnub.com/blog/device-presence-and-custom-state-with-pubnub-angular-2-sdk-part-two/

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub - using setState for isTyping

You just need to capture key press event to set state true and after a few seconds of no key press events or after publish (send button click), set state false. You set the state using this. [pubNubService.setState(...) API](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/angular2-javascript/api-reference-presence#user-state).

The key press events part is purely JS/Iconic and not PubNub specific so I will leave that to someone else to provide insights.

This is an [older blog but it demonstrates](https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/angularjs/chat-typing-indicators/) this very well.